# Speed of one frame with respect to another in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, relative-motion

To derive the Lorentz transformation we begin with the general relationship between two frames as below:

$x' = Ax + Bt$

$y' = y$

$z' = z$

$t' = Cx + Dt$

[image]

If frame $S'$ is moving at speed $v$ with respect to frame $S$, how can we say that the speed of frame $S$ with respect to frame $S'$ is $-v$ ?

(There is a similar question here. One answer has made up his own theory as people have commented there and ended up with negative votes the other one uses four vectors which is unnecessary since this question is  elementary for special relativity and indeed the textbook doesn't even mention four vectors in the derivation of Lorentz transformations. )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the relative velocity of B with respect to A negative of the relative velocity of A with respect to B?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156103/why-is-the-relative-velocity-of-b-with-respect-to-a-negative-of-the-relative-vel)

Comment: Thank you jonas, I'll read the answer an see.

Comment: Four-vectors are part of special relativity. In my opinion, it is the best way to approach special relativity. I don’t think it is good to dismiss answers based on four-vectors

Comment: I'm not dismissing answers, I'm just starting relativity and the first set of equations is the ones shown above.